# No distinguir entre may y minúsculas

Tags: java

Tengo este ejercicio que pide una palabra por pantalla y saca el primer carácter no repetido que encuentra, pero quisiera que no distinguiera entre mayúsculas y minúsculas ya que si encuentra una a y una A cree que son dos carácteres diferentes.
Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Palabra:");
    CaracterNoRepetido();
}

public static void CaracterNoRepetido() {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena = lector.nextLine();
    char car = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; !repetido && j < cadena.length(); j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                repetido = cadena.charAt(i) == cadena.charAt(j);
            }
        }


    System.out.println(car);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pasar la cadena de texto que te llega a minusculas antes de tratarla en el bucle for interno con el método toLowerCase;

```
String  textoConMyusculas = "Frase de tExto cualquierA";
String textoMinusculas = textoConMayusculas.toLowerCase();
```

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es convertir a minusculas la cadena ingresada mediante la función [**toLowerCase()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) :

```
 cadena = cadena.toLowerCase();
```

Este sería el código:

```
  public static void CaracterNoRepetido() {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cadena = lector.nextLine();

        //*Convierte a minusculas cadena.
        cadena = cadena.toLowerCase();

        char caracter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {

            boolean repetido = false;
            for (int j = 0; !repetido && j < cadena.length(); j++) {
                if (j != i) {
                    repetido = cadena.charAt(i) == cadena.charAt(j);
                }
            }

            if (!repetido) {
                caracter = cadena.charAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(caracter);
    }
```